# How one microservice in Ranking system should communicate to another microservice if the later one gives data required for ranking

Tags: microservices, system-design

I am designing a microservice that will rank users based on their actions taken such as the number of the correct answers given to questions.

A --> The system I am designing. It updates ranking based on the data from B and saves in a database.

B ---> The system that feeds data to A. Basically, it holds what action a particular user has performed.

Microservice A updates ranking based on the data from B.

I want to update the ranking of users once in a day. Let's say at midnight assuming as it's not critical data and I want A to avoid calculating the ranking of users on every action performed by them as it feeds data to B.

I believe I have two options to do it.

1. Make an API call from A to B and find all the new data based on timestamp at midnight.
2. Place a message broker between A and B. B being producer will produce messages and A will consume it.

Please let me know if they are valid ways to do it. If yes, which one is better or we can achieve it another way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both options might be used but with caveats.

Option A: Make API call once a day (perhaps midnight depending on locale)

- if number of records to fetch is expected to not grow too much it might be ok otherwise not feasible
- be careful you might overload other service if there are so many users to fetch their data and calculate
- this option has less complexity, easy to start with. Might be preferred if scale is not big at start

Option B: Message broker in between

- Make sure retention is configured in a way they will ve persisted long enough
- Since messages are buffered it provides more resiliency
- This scales better in time if your # of actions and user base grow quickly
- Message broker is additional complexity always but perhaps you can use something from cloud